# Assign macro to a button created in run time VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button, runtime

My question is basically answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically-using-vba-on-excel)

But instead of the class code below:

```
Sub CmdEvents_Click()
   MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

I need to run this code (it's just a sample, I want to use the name of the button clicked later in the program)

```
Sub CmdEvents_Click()
Dim mvCtrl As Control
Set mvCtrl = Me.ActiveControl
MsgBox mvCtrl.Name
End Sub
```

But this code above will NOT, by any means return correctly the Name of the button I just created in run time in the message box.

It returns "Button 6".... I did a search in my workbook and I don't even have this name.

I actually I modified the original code from the link above to get the names of the buttons all from a list. This way I can modify the list, thus modifying the name of the buttons, or caption if I want to. And this Button 6 doesn't even exists in my list.

I made some traps in my code, showing message boxes for the variable I use to get the button name from, and it's correct, it's carrying the string I want to name my button before it creates it.

Comment: How have you set the Button `Name`? The link shows an answer which only sets the `Caption`

Comment: Assuming you followed the post you linked to, your class instance already contains a variable `CmdEvents` which references the clicked button, so you can use `Msgbox CmdEvents.Name`  If your code is different, it would be useful to post the relevant parts so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams you just totally nailed it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TimWilliams - please convert your comment into an answer so the user can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you followed the post you linked to, your class instance already contains a variable `CmdEvents` which references the clicked button, so you can use

```
Msgbox CmdEvents.Name
```

If your code is different, it would be useful to post the relevant parts so we can see what's going on.