# How do you control a button inside a multipage in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, multipage, commandbutton

I have a multipage, I was successfully able to copy elements of the first page which is my reference page to new pages which is created dynamically.

My question is, how do I set a commandbutton's actions inside a page in a multipage control?
My goal is to click on the button from any page then pops up another form.

How do I do this?
It's pretty hard to adjust from Android to VB. I really appreciate any help from you guys.

This is my code in cloning pages.

```
i = 0
MultiPage1.Pages.Add
MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls.Copy
i = i + 1
MultiPage1.Pages(i).Paste
For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls
     If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.Label Then
           '~~~ code omitted
           Select Case ctl.Tag
                Case "startTime"
                        ctl.Caption = "4:00pm"
           End Select
     End If
Next
```

this is how it's going to look like.
[image]

the button will concatenate all strings inside the page. the concatenated string will be shown on another userform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably would be better off creating a button in the ribbon so that it is available on all pages:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/02/27/how-to-add-your-own-macros-to-excel-ribbon/

EDIT:

My bad, I thought you meant a worksheet instead of a VBA MultiPage in a userform.

Check this out. I was able to make this work for me:

[Assign code to a button created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically-using-vba-on-excel)

Class1:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()
    MsgBox "yo"
End Sub
```

Userform with MultiPage object:

```
Option Explicit

Dim cmdArray() As New Class1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim newControl As Control

    Set newControl = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "NewCommand", True)

    newControl.Object.Caption = "hello"


    newControl.Left = 50
    newControl.Top = 50

    ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To 1)
    Set cmdArray(1).CmdEvents = newControl

    Set newControl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer joseph. I was thinking of that way as well for it is easier but, I have a reason why I raised this question. I wanted to know if there is a way to do it. what if there are buttons inside a page which is different from the buttons on the other page. how will you solve it? that is why I raised this question.

Comment: Ah, I see. It used to be much easier and I haven't had the chance to really look at customizing the ribbon. However, there is a really nice resource that I found that you can take a look at: http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm - take a look at the example workbooks. I'll come back to this when I have time to check it out.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I really appreciate your suggestion. If all else fails, then my choice will be Ribbons.

Comment: @JovanniG sure thing. I misunderstood your request. When you said pages, I thought you meant worksheets. I see you are using a userform with a MultiPage control. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: dude it worked. I guess it's much better if I create the buttons and labels rather than copying them from the first page. Thanks a lot dude. you rock.

Comment: @JovanniG nice! Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom class. The class basically has one member `Public WithEvents b as CommandButton`.

The trick is the `WithEvents` keyword. You can now insert some code to generically handle the click of a button that is assigned to this class:

```
Private Sub b_Click()
    MsgBox "You clicked " & b.Name 'Modify this event so that different code is executed base on the page/name/etc.
End Sub
```

In order to make this work, you need to assign the button you create in your code to an object of this new class:

```
Private objButtonHandler as New MyClass 'this should be scope a UserForm wide

Sub YourSub
    Dim objYourButton as CommandButton
    Set objYourButton = ... `your code here
    Set objButtonHandler.b = objYourButton
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Peter, I don't somehow understand what to put on the "`your code here". The buttons were a clone from the reference page which is Page(0) on the Multipage. And the pages as well as it's contents are dynamically created. I can post my code here if you'd like.

Comment: @JovanniG: How do you clone the page? Maybe you can access the button with something like this: `Set objYourButton = MyMultipage.Pages(MyMultipage.Pages.Count).Controls(1)` You might need to replace the `1` with the number for the button...

Comment: I see. Now I get it. I will try this one out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JovanniG: Great! Let me know how it went!

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not worked. I added images on my question and a code snippet to clarify everything as well.