# Move a dynamic created control on a form using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have created a form. On this form I have created 3 buttons.

I want to be able to move these button at runtime.

The problem which I have is how do I reference the buttons at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Me.Controls("CommandButton1").Move 0, 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem which I have is how do I reference the buttons at runtime?

It depends on how are you assigning the names to the button.

Here is a simple way to create a command button at runtime and move it using another button

```
Option Explicit

Const CmdName As String = "Click_Me"

Dim ctl_Command As Control

'~~> Create command button on the fly
'~~> and give it a predefined name
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set ctl_Command = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", CmdName, False)

    With ctl_Command
        .Left = 100
        .Top = 100
        .Width = 255
        .Caption = "Blah Blah"
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Use that name to move the control
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim X As Double, Y As Double

    X = 5: Y = 5.5

    Set ctl_Command = Me.Controls(CmdName)
    ctl_Command.Move X, Y
End Sub
```

In case you are creating multiple dynamic controls then you can use a variable and increment it to assign names. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically-using-vba-on-excel/10224992#10224992) example. In that link, see the line

```
Set ctl_Command = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CmdXYZ" & i, False)
```

Notice `"CmdXYZ" & i`?