# How can I reference a dynamically created control in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, reference, controls

I've been finding the answers I need here on StackOverflow for months (thank you all!) but so far my search terms aren't finding the result I need this time... hence, my first post here...

I have an Excel file that includes two UserForms:

- The first is used to input certain invoice data and then export that data in a format that can be uploaded into our proprietary accounting system.
- The second is later used to post payment data against those invoices and then, similarly, export that data in a format that can be uploaded into our accounting system.

The second form has to be created dynamically in Userform_Initialize, because the number of payments required (and, thus, the number of TextBox and Label controls created) varies depending on the size of the invoices.  I've finished the code to create this second form and it works well, but I'd like to add some functionality that is triggered when some of these dynamically created controls are changed by the user.

I've done this in other forms using a given control's _Change() procedure (for example, when I want to move to the next box after entering a dollar amount, I use _Change() to SetFocus elsewhere as soon as the value has two digits after the decimal).  So my question is: how can I establish _Change()-style procedures for controls that don't yet exist before the form is initialized?  Is there a way to set a "global" _Change() procedure that I can use to loop through text boxes and use if/then/else statements based on their dynamic names?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592641/assign-event-handlers-to-controls-on-user-form-created-dynamically-in-vba

Comment: [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically-using-vba-on-excel)

Comment: And [Another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932711/move-a-dynamic-created-control-on-a-form-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

When I am using dynamic forms, I like to create object arrays to store the relevant information so that I can quickly and easily reference the objects by "name".