# VBA Copy and Paste controls on userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have to create a user form in VBA for an excel workbook. At runtime the user needs to add to a group of controls to the user form every time they click an add button. The group of controls consists of a couple of text boxes, a few option buttons and a couple of buttons. I created a control template that consist of all the controls I need arranged in a frame. I'd like to just copy the predesigned group and past it into a frame. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Why copy it when you can create at runtime? You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically-using-vba-on-excel/10224992#10224992)

Comment: That is a very good option for sure and may be how I have to go. I was hoping by creating the control grouping ahead of time in a frame I could avoid positioning all eight controls each time they click add. The client would like to see a list of these control groups. Were it a win forms app I'd be done but the constraints force me to use VBA.