# VBA: Events for several dynamically added buttons

Tags: vba, excel, runtime, userform

I am adding several CommandButtons dynamically to my user form. To assign code, I used the answer of this question: [Assign code to a button created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically)

However, I need to determine which button has been clicked. They all do have different names. Therefore, my initial idea was to get the name of the clicked button in the `CmdEvents_Click()` procedure. However, I have not found a solution how to do that.

Does anyone have a solution how to trigger button specific events?

Comment: It should be possible. Add the Name of the new command e.g. like```ctl_Command.Name = "name_" & i``` and then in the ```CmdEvents_Click``` just use ```CmdEvents.Name```.

Comment: if you add this as an answer, I'll give you a green checkmark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add the `Name` of the new command e.g. like `ctl_Command.Name = "name_" & i`
- Then in the `CmdEvents_Click` just use `CmdEvents.Name`.