# How to create _Change() Event for dynamically created TextBox in VBA UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to add **_Change() event** to dynamically created TextBox using classes in VBA. However there is nothing happening, when I try to run my code. Could you please point me where I am wrong?

I have got class **conditionEventClass**

```
Public WithEvents conditionEvent As MSForms.textBox

Public Property Let textBox(boxValue As MSForms.textBox)
    Set conditionEvent = boxValue
End Property

Public Sub conditionEvent_Change()
    MsgBox conditionEvent.Name & " changed."
End Sub
```

I have got following code in my module:

```
Sub addConditions()
    Dim conditionCommand As conditionEventClass
    Dim newTextBox As MSForms.textBox
    

        
    Set newTextBox = commandRequestForm.MultiPage1(1).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "conditionValue", True)
    With newTextBox
         .Name = "conditionValue"
         .Left = 750
         .height = 15
         .Width = 100
         .Top = 20 
    End With
    
    Set conditionCommand = New conditionEventClass
    conditionCommand.textBox = newTextBox
    
End Sub
```

I expect that my sub **conditionEvent_Change()** is going to show msgBox. But unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about only a single Text Box, you can use the next simpler way:

1.Declare a private variable on top of the form code module (in the declarations area):

```
    Private WithEvents myTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
```

2. Then, create the event for the above declared variable:

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Change()
   MsgBox activecontrol.name & " changed."
End Sub
```

3. Use your adapted code as:

```
Sub addConditions()
    Dim newTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

    Set newTextBox = commandRequestForm.MultiPage1(1).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "myTextBox", True)
    With newTextBox
         .left = 10
         .height = 15
         .width = 100
         .top = 20
    End With
    
    Set myTextBox = newTextBox
End Sub
```

For 1 to 3, 4 such controls you can use the simpler (above shown) way. If you need creating on the fly a lot of such controls, I can show you how to adapt your code...

**Edited**:

Please, use the next working way using a class to be assigned to many text boxes created on the fly:

1. Copy the next code in a class module and **name it 'clsTBox'**:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents newTBox As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub newTBox_Change()
   MsgBox newTBox.name & " changed."
End Sub
```

2.Declare a `Private` variable on top of the form code module:

```
  Private TBox() As New clsTBox
```

3. Use the next `Sub` to create three text boxes and assign the `Click` event to them:

```
Private Sub CreateThreeTB() 
    Dim i As Long, txtBox01 As MSForms.TextBox, leftX As Double, tWidth As Double, k As Long
    
    leftX = 20: tWidth = 50
    ReDim TBox(100) 'use here the maximum number of text boxes you intend creating
    For i = 1 To 3
         Set txtBox01 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "dynTxtBox_" & i)
        With txtBox01
            .top = 10
            .left = leftX: leftX = leftX + tWidth
            .width = tWidth
            .Text = "something" & i
        End With
        
        Set TBox(k).newTBox = txtBox01: k = k + 1
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve TBox(k - 1)
End Sub
```

4. Call the above `Sub` from `Initialize` event or from another control, play with the newly created text boxes value and see how the change event is triggered...

Comment: Thanks - very well-done. I already figured it out and created already many textboxes on the fly with Collection.

Comment: @Nik Ohler Glad I could help! I will edit my answer and place a piece of code using a (simpler) class and an array of classes. Just for the sake of showing alternatives...