# Excel vba open windows folder with button

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a challenge and cant solve it, i have excel vba where i have a UserFrom1. In this UserForm1 is a button, as soon as I click the button UserForm2 opens, there are 2 TextBoxes and a button. In Textbox1 I enter and the values are in column A2 to A.... the same is also saved for texbox2 the values are then saved in B2 to B.... (of course they are saved as soon as I click the button in UserForm2.

Now I have a code that does the following. It takes the values from A2 to A.... and automatically creates buttons in UserForm1 with the names in A2 to A.... so if, for example, A2 contains "App", then a button called "App" is automatically generated in UserForm1. And that up to infinity how many entries I then also have in column A. The code is written below.

I want to make things a little more complicated and have been working on it for a few days but have not found a solution. I always enter links in column B which lead to Windwos Order e.g. C:\User\App, this link should open when I click the button "App". the same applies to A3, if there is "System" and in B3 C:\User\System the generated button with name "System" in UserForm1 should open the link with C:\User\System. Hope it was understandable so far.

Here is my code for automatic button generation.

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    With UserForm1
        ' last for A find
        Dim lastRowA As Long
        lastRowA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' reverse
        Dim i As Long
        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "CommandButton" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Button_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

       
        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 10 ' Start position

        For i = 2 To lastRowA
            ' Creating button
            Dim newButton As MSForms.CommandButton
            Set newButton = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button_" & i - 1, True)

            ' Creating Button
            With newButton
                .Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Left = 10
                .Top = topOffset
                .Width = 120
                .Height = 20
            End With

         

            ' Position
            topOffset = topOffset + 30 ' area Between buttons
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

After some additions on code here my whole code:

**UserForm1:**

[image: UserForm1]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub SaveClose_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm3.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub EditMode_Click()
    Application.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

**UserForm2:**

[image: UserForm2]

```
Private Sub Liste_Click()
    UserForm2.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub SaveList_Click()
    ' Daten aus den Textboxen holen
    Dim value1 As String
    Dim value2 As String

    value1 = UserForm2.TextBoxName.Value
    value2 = UserForm2.TextBoxLink.Value

    ' Daten in Tabelle schreiben
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ' Letzte Zeile finden
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ' Daten in die Zellen schreiben
        .Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = value1
        .Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = value2
    End With

    ' Excel-Datei speichern
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    ' UserForm1 neu initialisieren (Buttons erstellen)
    UserForm1_Initialize

End Sub








Private Sub SaveClose_Click()
    UserForm2.Hide
    UserForm3.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub

Private Sub EditMode_Click()
    Application.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

**Module1:**

```
Option Explicit
Dim cmdArray() As New Klasse1

Sub showLoginForm()
    If isSheetVisible Then
        ' Only Hide this workbook and keep the other workbooks visible
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
        ' There is no other workbook visible, hide Excel
        Application.Visible = False
    End If
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Function isSheetVisible() As Boolean
    ' Checks if any workbook except the current one is visible
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
            Dim win As Window
            For Each win In wb.Windows
                If win.Visible Then isSheetVisible = True
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    With UserForm1
        ' last for A find
        Dim lastRowA As Long
        lastRowA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim conts(1 To lastRowA - 1) As Klasse1   'array for the classes

        ' reverse
        Dim i As Long
        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "CommandButton" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Button_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

       
        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 10 ' Start position

        For i = 2 To lastRowA
            ' Creating button
            Dim newButton As MSForms.CommandButton
            Set newButton = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button_" & i - 1, True)

            ' Creating Button
            With newButton
                .Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Left = 10
                .Top = topOffset
                .Width = 120
                .Height = 20
                .Tag = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value
            End With
            ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To i)
            Set cmdArray(i).CmdEvents = newButton

            Set newButton = Nothing
         

            ' Position
            topOffset = topOffset + 30 ' area Between buttons
        Next i
    End With

    
End Sub
```

**Class1:**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()
    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & CmdEvents.Tag, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Tag = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "B").Value`.

Comment: worked. Thanks. Now its running

Comment: @VBasic2008 can you help me maybe here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036325/filter-buttons-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the click event of the generated CommandButtons. For this create a class module named `Class1` with this code, where Sheets(1) is the same sheet as in yours.

```
Public WithEvents contbutts As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub contbutts_click()
clicked_no = Mid(contbutts.Caption, 8)
Sheets(1).Cells(clicked_no + 1, 2).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

Insert the assignment into your code

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    With UserForm1
        ' last for A find
        Dim lastRowA As Long
        lastRowA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim conts(1 To lastRowA - 1) As Class1   'array for the classes

        ' reverse
        Dim i As Long
        For i = .Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "CommandButton" Then
                If Left(.Controls(i).Name, 7) = "Button_" Then
                    .Controls.Remove i
                End If
            End If
        Next i

       
        Dim topOffset As Integer
        topOffset = 10 ' Start position

        For i = 2 To lastRowA
            ' Creating button
            Dim newButton As MSForms.CommandButton
            Set newButton = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button_" & i - 1, True)

            ' Creating Button
            With newButton
                .Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Left = 10
                .Top = topOffset
                .Width = 120
                .Height = 20
            End With
            Set conts(i - 1) = New Class1    'create a class for the button
            Set conts(i - 1).contbutts = newButton  'assign the button to the class's button to catch the click event.

         

            ' Position
            topOffset = topOffset + 30 ' area Between buttons
        Next i
    End With
    UserForm1.Show
    
End Sub
```

On your sheet when you add the button name in col.A immediately create a link to anywhere (e.g. folder) in col.B Then there is no need of second userform and anything else.

This is the sheets(1) content:

[image]

Comment: didnt work realy, nothing opened after clicking :( I adjusted my codes and posted with pictures on my question (I edited it now)

Comment: Added the screenshot of Sheets(1) data how is it should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.Tag` property to store the path. BTW intellisense will not give you access to property but trust me it works (**Demonstration below**). Here is an example.

Let's say we have 2 userforms. `UserForm1` and `UserForm2`

Paste this code in the `Userform1`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim frm As New UserForm2
    
    With frm
        Dim newButton As MSForms.CommandButton
        Set newButton = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "ButtonA", True)

        ' Creating Button
        With newButton
            .Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
            .Left = 10
            .Top = 10
            .Width = 120
            .Height = 20
            '~~> This is where you store the path
            .Tag = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value
        End With
        
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

And to launch the path, simply use `Shell`

```
Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & Btn.Tag, vbNormalFocus
```

Also please see [Assign code to a button created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically) on how to assign code to a button created dynamically. Use the above `Shell` command in the class module.

**Demonstration**

Let's say my worksheet looks like this

[image]

Let's say my `Userform1` looks like this

[image]

Let's say my `Userform2` looks like this

[image]

Code in `Userform1`

```
Option Explicit

Dim cmdArray() As New Class1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim frm As New UserForm2
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    
    With frm
        Dim newButton As MSForms.CommandButton
        Set newButton = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "ButtonA", True)
    
        ' Creating Button
        With newButton
            .Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
            .Left = 10
            .Top = 10
            .Width = 120
            .Height = 20
            '~~> This is where you store the path
            .Tag = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value
        End With
            
        ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To i)
        Set cmdArray(i).CmdEvents = newButton

        Set newButton = Nothing
    
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Code in Class Module `Class1`

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()
    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & CmdEvents.Tag, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: okay, i have combined my code and your code because it is slightly different for me. And in my UserForm1 there is a button which opens UserForm2. In UserForm2 I type the lines A and B, which are then saved in excel. Then I click on a button in UserForm2 so that the buttons are generated in UserForm1. I have implemented your code so that now something opens as soon as I click on the generated button but only explorer opens nothing more.

Comment: I would like to send my whole code to you that you can see it but i dont know how.

Comment: okay, I just edited my question with pictures and my whole code. Hope you can understand it and what i want. Would be very happy to solve the issue :)

Comment: an you help me maybe here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036325/filter-buttons-excel-vba